# screen freezes when i want to dual boot ubuntu 18.04 on my zenbook

Tags: usb-installation

windows 10 is already installed on my laptop. when I select install ubuntu in boot screen the purple page opens but after some seconds the screen just freezes and nothing happens. I tried writing acpi=off or nomodeset in the editing scrren but niether of them worked. could u please help me?
I tryed nomodeset like this : in the boot screen I selected install ubuntu but instead of enter I pressed e. then the edit screen opened and I added nomodeset at the end of the line that starts with linux after quiet splash. Then I pressed f10 and it caused an error that said end kernel panic not syncing vfs.

Comment: `nomodeset` should work. How did you add the boot parameter?

Comment: in the boot screen I selected install ubuntu but instead of enter I pressed e. then the edit screen opened and I added nomodeset at the end of the line that starts with linux after quiet splash. Then I pressed f10 and it caused an error that said end kernel panic not syncing vfs.

Comment: Please [edit] to add all that Info to the question. Next I suggest googling your brand/model + Ubuntu. The results may suggest additional boot parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write nomodeset before quiet splash and it worked.Then I installed ubuntu and when it was done I tried to update my video drivers using these commands in the terminal:

sudo add-apt-get-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-384 # or the latest driver

then I restarted my pc and now it works properly.